# Could not find the correct Provider<xxx> above this xxxx Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new in flutter currently would like to do data fetching from Firebase and Display it at Home Screen however it coming error such this which I'm not clear what's is going on? Error code as below

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that UserProfileItem is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

In my main have using multiple provider

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, UserProfileLogic>(
          update: (ctx, auth, previousProfile) => UserProfileLogic(
            auth.token,
            auth.userId,
            previousProfile == null ? [] : previousProfile.items,
          ),
          create: null,
        ),
```

In user_profile_item.dart file tried to moving declare what's showing in the Home Screen. I have some option here either using constructor and pass this entire function to Home Screen and call Provider in the build context however it failed as well so I change the option to declare the provider in this class and call this method also couldn't work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/user_profile.dart';

class UserProfileItem extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String username;
  // final String age;
  // final String gender;
  // final String bio;

  // UserProfileItem(this.username, this.age, this.gender, this.bio);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<UserProfile>(context, listen: false);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          elevation: 6,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                        "assets/images/Materials-25.png",
                      ),
                      radius: 70,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(product.username),
              Text(product.username),
              Text(product.username),
              Text(product.username),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Home_Screen to display however it also coming error as above and as mention I trying in both way but it's failed as well

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final product = Provider.of<UserProfile>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        // "Navigator.push" returns a Future and "onPressed" accepts void
        //so cannot directly use "Navigator" but if using () =>
        //simply means that executing "Navigator..."
        onPressed: () =>
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SocialProfileScreen.routeName),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Meetups"),
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body: UserProfileItem(),
    );
  }
```

(Home_screen)I have been fetch data from Firebase already is there any fast solution based on my cases to get user data directly?

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<UserProfileLogic>(context).fetchAndSetUserProfile().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

This is the way how I fetch from database

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetUserProfile([bool filterByUser = false]) async {
    final filterString =
        filterByUser ? "orderBy='creatorId'&equalTo='$userId'" : '';

    var url = Uri.parse(
        "https://meetup-aed5f-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/userprofile/$userId.json?auth=$authToken$filterString"); // this mean creatorId equal to userId
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
      final List<UserProfile> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(UserProfile(
          userprofileid: prodId,
          username: prodData['username'],
          age: prodData['age'],
          gender: prodData['gender'],
          bio: prodData['bio'],
        ));
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably return an instance of UserProfileLogic in your Provider’s create field!

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, UserProfileLogic>(
      update: (ctx, auth, previousProfile) => UserProfileLogic(
        auth.token,
        auth.userId,
        previousProfile == null ? [] : previousProfile.items,
      ),
      create: (ctx) => UserProfileLogic(null, null, []),
    ),
```